# plot two columns as a bar graph and third column as line graph ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

My df looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c('2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'),
                 "alo" = c(10, 11, 12.5, 9),
                 "bor" = c(18, 20, 23, 19),
                 "car" = c(100, 125, 110, 102)) %>%
  gather(-date, key = "key", value = "value")
```

I want to plot alo and bor columns as two bar graphs on the same plot so I gather the df. However, I want the car column as a line graph instead of a bar plot on the same graph.

Currently, my plotting code is:

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, value, fill = key)) +
           geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge")
```

Please advice on how I can add line graph for third column instead of bar. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only `gather` the columns you want in your bargraph:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c('2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'),
                 "alo" = c(10, 11, 12.5, 9),
                 "bor" = c(18, 20, 23, 19),
                 "car" = c(100, 125, 110, 102)) %>%
  gather(alo, bor, key = "key", value = "value")

ggplot(df, aes(date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value, fill = key), position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(aes(y = car, group = 1))
```

[image]

If you want a `car` label in your legend, do some trickery:

```
ggplot(df, aes(date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value, fill = key), position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(aes(y = car, group = 1, col = 'car')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = 'black') +
  labs(color = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: @Moshee I'd stick to the solution above, but if you `gather` all columns you can then use the appropriate subset of data to pass to `geom_col` and `geom_line`. Like: `ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df %>% filter(key != "car"), aes(date, value, fill = key), position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(data = df %>% filter(key == "car"), aes(date, value, group = 1))`

Comment: @AntoniosK, as a further trick, you can actually pass a function to the data argument, which means you can use e.g. `geom_col(data = . %>% filter(key != "car") .....`, so you don't have to define your data.frame multiple times.